# Multiple separate Pickerviews in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uipickerview

I am new to programming, so please forgive the basic nature of this question.

I am trying to put multiple picker views into the same class, but they keep coming back with the same choices.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UIPickerViewDelegate{

@IBOutlet var outgoing: UIPickerView!

var var1=["1","2"]
var var2=["a","b"]

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
}

func numberOfComponentsInPickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView!) ->Int{
    return 2
}


func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView!, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) ->Int {

    return var1.count


}


func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView!, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int)->String!{
    return var2[row]

}
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: You mean, you need to show both picker in same class ?

Comment: They need to show up in the same controller, so I thought the code was in the same class.  (Is my terminology incorrect?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For displaying two components you need to change your methods like:

```
func numberOfComponentsInPickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView!) ->Int
{
       return 2
}


func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView!, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) ->Int
{
    var rows = var2.count
    if component == 0
    {
        rows = var1.count
    }
    return rows;
}


func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView!, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int)->String!
{
    var componentStr = var2[row]
    if component == 0
    {
        componentStr = var1[row]
    }
    return componentStr;
}
```

Comment: That kind of worked, but I am trying to put a completely unrelated picker on the same controller.  When I add the additional controller it just shows the var1 array.  How would I do it if I wanted to add a 3rd array?

Comment: @AndyDewan: It's a new question. If you add a new picker add tags to them and use tag to distinguish between them.